# How to create and initialize an object without a View in ASP .NET MVC with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, view, controller

I have two tables Movie and Rental in a local database. Rental has a field called itemID that is a foreign key references to id in Movie.

I used Entity Framework for the two tables, which, in turn, create the following two classes:

```
public partial class Movie
{   
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public virtual Rental Rental { get; set; }
}

public partial class Rental
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int itemID { get; set; }
    public string renterName { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime date { get; set; }
    public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a Rental object in RentalController while in /Movie/Details/2. Thus, I modified Movie/Details.cshtml to the following:

```
@model Project.Models.Movie

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Movie</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.Raw(Model.name)
    </dd>

    <dd>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Rental", new { id = Model.id, returnURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath }, FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "createForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <a class="navbar-nav" href="javascript:document.getElementById('createForm').submit()">Rent</a>
        }
    </dd>
</dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.id }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

This is where I got myself lost. How do I create a Rental object and save it correctly to the database?

```
public class RentalController : Controller
{
    private CatalogEntities db = new CatalogEntities();

    // POST: Rental/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(int id, string returnURL)
    {
        Rental rental = new Rental() { itemID = id, renterName = "User" };
        db.Rentals.Add(rental);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Redirect(returnURL);
    }
}
```

While I didn't get an error after clicking on **Rent**, no entry is added to Rental table. I wonder if it is because rental object has a null reference to Movie property and that particular Movie object has no reference to the rental object. Even so, I can't figure how to pass that Movie object from view to controller.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in a controller to see if it is hit?

Comment: Yes, it indeed runs the db.SaveChanges(), but nothing is saved to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. It apparently was working earlier except I was querying it wrong. That explains why I didn't get any error back when it was written back to the database.

Going back to the question at hand, in order to create and initialize an object with a reference to another object, you just need to create that object with the correct key reference, which is the Movie ID referred as **itemID**. While the reference to Series for the new object is null during **that particular run-time**, it is sufficient to use to write back to the database. Thus, the code below is really all I need:

```
Rental rental = new Rental() { itemID = id };
db.Rentals.Add(rental);
db.SaveChanges();
```

The reason why this works is because when the page get redirected, the database is read again and all Rental objects are recreated. If the new Rental object is referenced correctly, it will automatically load up the correct Movie object and attach it to the new Rental object.